# Navigate by checking login state with jetpack compose (Conditional Nested Nav graphs)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to implement a way to check authentication status from the room database before and navigate (Conditional navigation)

The requirement is as follows

[image]

I have a session manager with the following code

```
    private val _sessionState = MutableStateFlow(SessionState.Loading)
    val sessionState: StateFlow<SessionState> = _sessionState

    init {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            sessionRepo.getActiveSession()
                .collect { resource ->
                    _sessionState.value = when (resource) {
                        is Resource.Success -> {
                            if (resource.data == null) {
                                SessionState.InActive
                            } else {
                                SessionState.Active
                            }
                        }
                        else -> throw IllegalStateException("Failed to load session")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

How can I check this with jetpack compose

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your question correctly I would do it this way:

```
@Composable
fun App(mainViewModel: MainViewModel) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        mainViewModel.checkAuth(navController)
    }
    
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = RootNavigation.Home.route
    ) {
        
        composable(RootNavigation.Home.route) {
            SplashScreen()
        }

        loginGraph(navController)

        workspaceGraph(navController)
    }
}
```

At MainViewModel:

```
fun checkAuth(navController: NavHostController) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        ...//your code
        
        if (resource.data == null)                            
            navController.navigateAndReplaceStartRoute(RootNavigation.Login.route)
        else navController.navigateAndReplaceStartRoute(RootNavigation.Workspace.route)

        ...//your code
    }
}
```

Did I answer your question?

Comment: +1 Thanks, I will try using this approach and give you feedback. Do you have any project or sample open source project on GitHub that is using this approach?

Comment: @EmmanuelMtali Sorry, I don't have an open source sample. Perhaps, this documentation will also help you https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nested-nav

Comment: Viewmodel must not know about navigation logic. This violates MVVM pattern. It becomes hard to unit test the viewmodel.

Answer (score 2):

So, for me is easier doing it this way

```
@Composable
fun NavigationGraph(
    navController: NavHostController
) {

    val currentUser = Firebase.auth.currentUser
    val startRoute = if(currentUser != null) NavigationScreens.HomeScreen else NavigationScreens.LoginScreen

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = startRoute.route) { ... }
```

Since `Firebase.auth` is a singleton that can be accessed from anywhere, you can check in your `NavGraph` before creating it if the user is not null, if so, there is a current logged in user , if there is a user logged in, just show home screen, else login.

If someone is interesed on what `NavigationScreens` is.

```
sealed class NavigationScreens(val route: String) {
 object HomeScreen: NavigationScreens("home_screen")
 object LoginScreen: NavigationScreens("login_screen")
}
```

The solution given from **@ngalashev** could potentially open the HomeScreen before the validation inside `mainViewModel.checkAuth(navController)` returns to navigate to the `LoginScreen`. Also it could add the HomeScreen to the backstack